# How to add webview to listview

Tags: android

I want to create a listview which contains webview on each row.Webviews are added to a relative layout dynamically.How can i do this? Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unlikely to work well. You cannot generally put scrollable things, like a `WebView`, into rows of a `ListView`.

If the HTML you are trying to display is limited, use `TextViews` for the rows, converting your HTML into something a `TextView` can use via `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: But i want to justify left and right side of the text.How to achieve this using TextView?